# Using ng-disabled the opposite way

Tags: angularjs

Firstly. I'm sorry if my title is not descriptive enough. I am a Junior Dev and new so my terminology may not be upto scratch. Please feel free to correct me.

I am using AngularJS and I am trying to enable a button when a checkbox is checked.

Here is my sample code:

```
<label>Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"></label><br/>
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
```

At the moment this works by disabling the button when it is checked. I need it the other way. Enable the button when checked.

Appreciate all your help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a **`NOT`** in front of checked

```
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="!checked">Button</button>
```

Comment: I can accept the answer in 12 mins. Thank you. I did not think I could use `!` inline like that.

Comment: @Mark using `checked` (**truthy** value) is the same as `checked == true`, so to get a negation, you would need `checked != true` or simply `!checked`

Comment: Thank you @AlekseySolovey :)